# Magento : get customer_id from salesOrderList

Tags: java, android, api, magento, soap

i try to get orderl list with this API : [salesOrderList (SOAP V2)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.list.html) , i use this code :

```
env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            env.dotNet = false;
            env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
            env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
                    "salesOrderList");
            request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
            //request.addProperty("customerId", id.toString());
            env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
            result = env.getResponse();
            Log.d("order result", result.toString());
```

and result :

```
increment_id=100000001;
                store_id=1; 
                created_at=2013-12-12 07:36:52; 
                updated_at=2013-12-12 07:36:57; 
                tax_amount=0.0000; 
                shipping_amount=0.0000; 
                discount_amount=0.0000; 
                subtotal=246.0000; 
                grand_total=246.0000; 
                total_qty_ordered=2.0000; 
                base_tax_amount=0.0000; 
                base_shipping_amount=0.0000; 
                base_discount_amount=0.0000; 
                base_subtotal=246.0000; 
                base_grand_total=246.0000; 
                billing_address_id=1; 
                billing_firstname=?????; 
                billing_lastname=????; 
                billing_name=????? ????; 
                store_to_base_rate=1.0000; 
                store_to_order_rate=1.0000; 
                base_to_global_rate=1.0000;
                base_to_order_rate=1.0000; 
                weight=0.0000; 
                store_name=Main Website
```

i have big problam ! there is no "customer_id" in result ! how can i get order list with id of order customer ?

Answer (score 1):

When I access the salesorder using php like following way

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index?wsdl=1');


$session = $client->login('testuser','testuser');

$result = $client->salesOrderList($session);
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
echo "<pre>";
?>
```

You will get following information using this you can get customer id.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [increment_id] => 100000001
            [store_id] => 1
            [created_at] => 2013-11-13 18:39:27
            [updated_at] => 2013-11-13 18:39:31
            [customer_id] => 1
            -----
            -----
            [customer_email] => xyz@example.com
```

Comment: i add returned result to my question